# When running executable I am getting "Something is wrong with flag 'grpc_experiments' in file config_vars.cc" what does it mean? How to solve this?

Tags: grpc

I am developing grpc services. I am using latest version of grpc and cmake version 3.22.1. I developed multiple grpc services and get their .so files. Then when I merge these .so files to create new executable I am getting error:

```
ERROR: Something is wrong with flag 'grpc_experiments' in file 'config_vars.cc'. One possibility: file 'config_vars.cc' is being linked both statically and dynamically into this executable. e.g. some files listed as srcs to a test and also listed as srcs of some shared lib deps of the same test.
```

I did not understand the error because I am getting this when I execute the code like ./code i tried

```
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_EXPERIMENTAL OFF)
```

in my cmakelists file but it did not work.

Is there anyone can help ?

NOTE:

Probably this error is because i am including protobuf and grpc twice because i have two different grpc service in different .so files.

Comment: Please update the post with more information: What versions of gRPC and cmake are you using? Are you trying to build a shared library? What specific command are you invoking to run your build?